# Error en constraint con un view dentro de otro

Tags: ios, xcode, objective-c

Tengo un view a modo de login con un label y una caja de texto. A su vez este view esta dentro del view principal de la vista.
Al ejecutar la aplicación no me muestra la vista con login bien y me sale el siguiente mensaje de aviso:

'[LayoutConstraints] Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. 
    Try this: 
        (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; 
        (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. 
(
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17009a770 _UILayoutGuide:0x10050e780.height == 20   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x170099ff0 V:|-(0)-[_UILayoutGuide:0x10050e780]   (active, names: '|':UIView:0x10050d2f0 )>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17009a810 _UILayoutGuide:0x10050eb30.height == 0   (active)>",
    "<_UILayoutSupportConstraint:0x17009a7c0 _UILayoutGuide:0x10050eb30.bottom == UIView:0x10050d2f0.bottom   (active)>",
    "",
    "",
    ""
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint

Make a symbolic breakpoint at UIViewAlertForUnsatisfiableConstraints to catch this in the debugger.
The methods in the UIConstraintBasedLayoutDebugging category on UIView listed in  may also be helpful.'

Las constraints las tengo puesta como en la imagen que adjunto:

[image: Constraints con un View de Login]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No puedo comentar, por lo que tomar esto como comentario:

Tienes demasiadas Constraints que generan conflicto.

Si usas el leading space, no utilizes el trailing space para la misma combinación de vistas.

Deberías revisar la documentación de [AutoLayout](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/)

También para poder ofrecerte más ayuda, sería conveniente incluir una captura del layout visual donde aparezcan las constraints [(en el editor de Xcode puedes marcar que aparezcan visibles las constraints)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13982844/add-constraint-not-listed-in-editor-menu-in-xcode)

Comment: En el editor de Xcode no me marca ningún conficto, es decir como si todo estuviera bien. Solo cuando compilo la aplicación es cuando la aplicación no funciona bien.

Comment: Pero quizá viendo una captura de cómo están vinculados los constraints dentro de la vista (es decir en el StoryBoard) pueda ver mejor cuál es la constraint que está generandote el conflicto.

Comment: Alfinal lo solucione centrando la vista interior en x e y, ademas dandole un height y width. 'View.centerY = centerY' y 'ViewCenterX = centerX'